# Move from Viewcontroller to another after image take

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

OK, I am a NOOB with iPhone and have a simple question I assume. I have found a lot of help out there but am not sure what I am doing wrong. I simply want to take a photo with the camera then move to the next view controller after successful capture and place it in an image view. Got most of this code from here so thanks already but can not seem to get it to work, all different kinds of errors I do not understand. I think it must be that I am killing the view controller then trying to re-instantiate it but am a little lost Please Help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)TakePhoto:(id)sender{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSString *submit = @"viewControllerSubmit";
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:submit bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:submit];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

As you can see I have tried a few things. I have tried searching for the errors but tried other things to no avail. Any assistance would be great, thanks in advance.

## EDITED VERSION and FULL CODE BELOW HERE

====================================================================
OK, I am posting my full code. I can get the form to go from one to the next as I was simply calling the storyboard name wrong. However I can not get the image I take from the camera to show up on the next form. All I get is an empty ImageView without any errors. What am I missing? Please help been working on this for days and have researched a ton.

First View Controller .M File

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewControllerSubmit.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController{

UIImage *newImage;

}


- (IBAction)TakePhoto:(id)sender{
    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil]; //nil from Null
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ViewControllerSubmit"]){
        ViewControllerSubmit *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.theNewImage = newImage;
    }
}

- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    newImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    NSString *submit = @"ViewControllerSubmit";
    NSString *main = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:main bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *vc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:submit];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}


- (void) imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

First View Controller .H File

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>{
    UIImagePickerController *picker;
}


@end
```

Second View Controller .M File

```
#import "ViewControllerSubmit.h"

@interface ViewControllerSubmit ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *_image;

@end

@implementation ViewControllerSubmit

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self._image.image = self.theNewImage;   
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Second View Controller .H File

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewControllerSubmit : ViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *theNewImage;

@end
```

Again, no error, the camera comes up, it takes the picture and when I click 'Use Photo' the second View Controller pops up but the image view does not show the image captured.

What am I missing? Any help would be great and again please forgive the ignorance, I am new to iPhone.

Comment: what are the errors . Please mention it in the question?

Comment: is your storyboard name same as your viewController name ?

Comment: forgive me, again new to iPhone and it is a little confusing. Well if I just run it without trying to bring up the other view controller, it takes the picture and goes back to the original controller. When I try to move to the 'viewControllerSubmit' controller, depending on which code I use as in the commented ones, I get different errors but I am currently getting with the code above 'Thread 1:signal SIGABRT' I am getting so confused. The stack says could not find a storyboard named 'viewControllerSubmit' in bundle. My storyboard is just named 'Main' by default.

Comment: OK, just got it thanks Mr. T. As suspected it was just something stupid due to my ignorance. All I needed was to identify the storyboard as a string then pass that as the storyboard identifier. Your comments guided me. Again sorry for the ignorance and thanks for the assist.

Comment: Not sure if I should re-post above. I just edited it thinking that was best. Still having an issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write navigation code in completion block...

Try below code,

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [imageView setImage:image];
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSString *submit = @"viewControllerSubmit";
        UIStoryboard *mainstoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:submit bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainstoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:submit];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];

}
```